# toStdString/toStdWString bug?

Tags: qt4

i used like this: (vs2010 + qt4.7)

```
std::wstring test2 = L""; 
QString test =tr("test");
test2 = test.toStdWString();
```

debug and found test2:

> 귢bĀ

anyone can help me?

Now i make it working like this:

```
std::wstring test2 = L""; 
QString test =tr("test");
test2.resize(test.length());test2.resize(test.toWCharArray(&(*test2.begin())));
```

i copy that from the toStdWString

Comment: Which debugger do you use? Are you sure this isn_t some artefact of the debugger?

Comment: change crt to vc90 from vc100,then everything is ok!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving old QT binaries to a different directory to make sure your program isn't linking against them eg. Old4.7.1.